# Can you flip perspective grid in Illustrator? Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, perspective

I am trying to make this perspective grid match the angle of the long side of this van. Is there a way in which I can flip the grid horizontally so the angle goes in the opposite direction? Then I can manipulate the grid from that.

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use Illustrator for this.  I'd use Photoshop for editing photos or for making a mockup like this. In Photoshop you can perspective distort a Smart Object.  A smart object can be an Illustrator document, or a raster image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **Perspective Grid Tool**, grab a handle and move it....

[image]

[Adobe's Perspective Grid help section](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/perspective-drawing.html)

You can move various grid points around with the Perspective Grid Tool and achieve a grid that works for you....

[image]

or...

[image]